# Can not remove generated DataBinding code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I used `DataBinding` in one of my classes `CardRecicleViewAdapterTech.class` , but I imported a library which does not support DataBinding and I switched to `butter knife`for that class.
The problem is that when I run the project, `Android Studio` always generates a class binding related with `CardRecicleViewAdapterTech.class`  and this causes a crash. The generated class is:

> CardViewTechBinding.java

I have deleted that java file in Android Studio databinding folder, but its generated again and again even when I do not use `databinding` anymore in my `xml` or my `class`.

This is my layout where I do not using dataBinding

> card_view_tech.xml

so that generate `CardViewTechBinding.java`  even when I am not using `dataBinding`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_tech"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_margin"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_view_technologie_name" />

            <com.pro.soft.apppresentation.ProgressWheel
                android:id="@+id/pw_spinner"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                ProgressWheel:pwText="Authenticating..."
                ProgressWheel:pwTextColor="#222"
                ProgressWheel:pwTextSize="14sp"
                ProgressWheel:pwRimColor="#330097D6"
                ProgressWheel:pwBarLength="60dp"
                ProgressWheel:pwBarColor="#0097D6"
                ProgressWheel:pwBarWidth="5dp"
                ProgressWheel:pwRimWidth="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I tried to restart my Pc and Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio but without success. Please help.

Comment: have you tried to clean a project?

Comment: yes I did, nothing changes

Comment: have you tried to disable it in build.gradle file?

Comment: I can not,  becouse I use it in a few clases

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In this order:

```
1.- Remove your file generated (build folder)
2.- Clean your project
3.- Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio
4.- Restart computer
```

Comment: Worked without restarting computer.

Comment: Have to do every time I make a change in the layout file. Any alternate to avoid it?

Comment: I'm did just the first step and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Project Span - > App -> build -> Generated.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and it was caused by having `<layout>` root tags in the XML. I did not realise that these tags were databinding related and the compiler also does not help you in this regard.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer that helped after I had tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

In app build.gradle disable it first by using:

`dataBinding {
        enabled = false;
    }`

and sync the project and then enable and sync the project

Comment: I think this is not answer.

Comment: I had a huge problem with gradle reusing some old generated binding files. Tried deleting gradle cache folder, restarting Android Studio etc., but this was the only solution (disable data binding - rebuild - enable data binding) which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by adding this to the build.gradle

```
buildFeatures {
  viewBinding false
}
```

and sync the project